# how to display the list of currencies in combobox in wpf and mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to populate the list of currencies in the combobox in wpf and mvvm. I tried adding the list of currencies to the combo box using the CultureInfo. Here is the code in the ViewModel

CurrenciesViewModel.cs

```
public List <CountryCurrencyPair> GetCountryList()
{
   return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
   .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID)).Distinct()
   .Select(r => new CountryCurrencyPair()
   {
    Country = r.EnglishName,
    Currency = r.CurrencyEnglishName
    }).ToList();
   }
```

I am binding with the ItemSource="{Binding GetCountryList}" in the combo box below. See the combobox code below:

MainPage.xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cmbCurrency" Width="100" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding GetCountryList}"
DisplayMemberPath="Country" SelectedValuePath="Currency"
SelectedValue="{Binding Currency, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

But the list does not populate the combobox.

Does anyone have the solution for the above problem?

Comment: Is the DataContext set?

Comment: `GetCountryList()` is a method. You can bind _only_ to properties. One option is to put a property in your view model that returns the list you want (either creates it each time in the getter or, preferably IMHO, caches and returns the result). Another option is to use the `<ObjectDataProvider/>` element, which while it does not allow binding directly to methods, does provide a mechanism to call methods from XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Use a List property in binding instead of a method

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCurrency"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="100" Height="30"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Country"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrencyList}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Currency,
                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Currency" />
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<CountryCurrencyPair> CurrencyList { get; set; } 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            CurrencyList = GetCountryList();
        }

        public List<CountryCurrencyPair> GetCountryList()
        {
            return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID)).Distinct()
            .Select(r => new CountryCurrencyPair()
            {
                Country = r.EnglishName,
                Currency = r.CurrencyEnglishName
            }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class CountryCurrencyPair
    {
       public string  Country {get;set;}
       public string Currency { get; set; }
    }
```